# Reference to generic type 'SomeResponse' requires arguments in <...>

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have getting the error "Reference to generic type 'SomeResponse' requires arguments in <...>"

```
struct SomeResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {

     let success: Bool

     let body: T?
}

final class SomeService {

    var response: SomeResponse? ///Reference to generic type 'SomeResponse' requires arguments in <...>

}
```

I don't fully understand the syntax of what I should write into the property "response"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should also be generic.

```
final class SomeService<T: Decodable> {
    var response: SomeResponse<T>?
}
```